# How to bookmark updatedInputs in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have an app with a lot of `updateNumericInputs` and I would like to be able to bookmark their state. I made the reprex incredibly small, but i still can point out the issue. I am reading about bookmarking - I am really confused, I suspect I need more lines of code, although from the pics I am attaching seems that I might be one comma away. I've been experimenting, trying to adopt code from tutorials, articles, SO answers, but I can't make it work. I would highly appreciate a solution and a lecture about it. 
Many thanks for your time!

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

          numericInput("Min", "Min",min = 0, max = 100, value = 42.5, step = 0.1),
          numericInput("Max", "Max", min = 0.0, max = 100, value = 47.4, step = 0.1),
          bookmarkButton(id = "bookmark")
    )



server <- function(input, output, session) {


  observeEvent(input$Max,{
    req(input$Max, input$Min)

    updateNumericInput(session,
                       "Min",
                       "Min",
                       value = input$Max - 0.1, min = 0.0, max = 100, step = 0.1)

  })




  observeEvent(input$bookmark,{
    reactiveValuesToList(input)
    session$doBookmark()
  })

}

enableBookmarking("url")

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

It is important to have the `ui` as a function with one argument `request`
`ui <- function(request) { fluidPage(....) }`
and in the server having `onRestore()` with vectors containing the current state of the inputs and then fed as a value to an `update..Input()`

```
library(shiny)


ui <-  function(request){
  fluidPage(

    numericInput("Min", "Min",min = 0, max = 100, value = 42.5, step = 0.1),
    numericInput("Max", "Max", min = 0.0, max = 100, value = 47.4, step = 0.1),
    bookmarkButton()
  )

}

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  observeEvent(input$Max,{
    req(input$Max, input$Min)
    updateNumericInput(session,
                       "Min",
                       "Min",
                       value = input$Max - 0.1, min = 0.0, max = 100, step = 0.1)

  })


    onRestored(function(state) {

      Min <- state$input$Min
      Max  <- state$input$Max
      updateNumericInput(session, "Min", value = Min,  min = 0.0, max = 100, step = 0.1)
      updateNumericInput(session, "Max", value = Max,  min = 0.0, max = 100, step = 0.1)
    })


}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```